# read through a dictionary for int

Tags: python, json, dictionary, typeerror

I am having some trouble with my code. I keep getting an error message when I try to run it and I can not figure out why.

Can someone please help?

```
import requests
import argparse
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen


url = "http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story&numericFilters=created_at_i>1488196800,created_at_i<1488715200"
r = urlopen(url)
data = r.read().decode("utf-8")
j_data = json.loads(data)

def build_structure(data, d=[]):
    if 'hits' in data:
        for t in data['hits']:
            d.append({'title' : t.get('title'), 'point' : t.get('points')})
            build_structure(t,d)
    return d

j = build_structure(j_data)
print(j)
word = "Python"
points = "2"
def structure_search_by_title(data, word, s=[]):
    for c in data:
        if word in c['title']:
            s.append({'title' : c.get('title')})
    return s

def structure_search_by_points(data, points, s=[]):
    for c in data:
        if points in c['point']:
            s.append({'Title of the article is' : c.get('title')})


k = structure_search_by_title(j, word)
l = structure_search_by_points(j, points)
print(k)
print(l)
```

Here's the error I'm getting

```
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Project1/Project1.py", line 36, in <module>
l = structure_search_by_points(j, points)
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Project1/Project1.py", line 31, in structure_search_by_points
if points in c['point']:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: You should give your variables more meaningful names. It makes debugging your program much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON returned from the API, `points` is an integer, not a string, so `c['point']` is an integer. So it doesn't make any sense to write:

```
if points in c['point']:
```

because `c['point']` is not a list or string that you can search. You should just use a simple equality test.

```
def structure_search_by_points(data, points, s=[]):
    points = int(points)
    for c in data:
        if points == c['point']:
            s.append({'Title of the article is' : c.get('title')})
    return s
```

Comment: This didn't work, i'm still getting the same error message

Comment: I don't see how that can be. Are you sure you saved the changes?

Comment: I see what I did wrong now, thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few notes on your code:

```
import requests
import argparse
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen


url = "http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story&numericFilters=created_at_i>1488196800,created_at_i<1488715200"
r = urlopen(url)
data = r.read().decode("utf-8")
j_data = json.loads(data)

def build_structure(data, d=[]):   # using a mutable as an initialiser
                                   # are you sure you know what you're doing?
    if 'hits' in data:
        for t in data['hits']:
            d.append({'title' : t.get('title'), 'point' : t.get('points')})
            build_structure(t,d)   # are you sure you want to call the
                                   # function recursively? (is the key
                                   # "hits" expected to occur in data["hits"]?
    return d

j = build_structure(j_data)
print(j)
word = "Python"
points = "2"
def structure_search_by_title(data, word, s=[]): # again, a mutable initialiser
    for c in data:
        if word in c['title']:
            s.append({'title' : c.get('title')}) # can use c['title'] here since
                                                 # you know 'title' is in c
    return s

def structure_search_by_points(data, points, s=[]): # another mutable
                                                    # initialiser
    for c in data:
        if points in c['point']:      # according to the error message
                                      # c['point'] is a single number
                                      # but 'in' expects something it can
                                      # search through, like a list
                                      # on top of that you points is a string
                                      # so the two cannot be compared directly
            s.append({'Title of the article is' : c.get('title')})


k = structure_search_by_title(j, word)
l = structure_search_by_points(j, points)
print(k)
print(l)
```

Comment: I did those initializers for cleaner code, so that any programmer can walk through it and understand what they were doing. As for the line with ['hits'], the original dictionary I get back from the json parsing is nested, to find all the data from the nested dictionary I had to make it recursive so I could find the hidden data. I am only having trouble with finding the ints inside of the hidden data and cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to read through the sorted array j and return the title value that matches the point value.

Comment: @KRose I'm not sure you fully grasp the problem with mutable initialisers (in case you do just ignore this), the emphasis being on mutable. If you call such a function twice and it modifies the variable, the variable won't be reset, so for example if you fill your `s=[]` during the first call, it won't be empty the second time. Worse, since you are returning s, both callers will receive _the same_ object. So if the first caller does something to `s`, the second caller's `s` will also change.